# Providing script from pipenv path in "pipenv run"

Tags: pipenv

amazon_kclpy_helper.py is installed with amazon_kclpy. It prints the output command that further is to be executed.

`amazon_kclpy_helper.py --print_command --java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java --properties /path/to/my.properties`

I wish to use pipfile scripts to run it so I do not have to provide the command and path every time.

Pipfile:

```
[scripts]
mycmd = "`amazon_kclpy_helper.py --print_command --java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java --properties /path/to/my.properties`"
```

If I run `pipenv run mycmd`:
Error: the command `amazon_kclpy_helper.py (from mycmd) could not be found within PATH.

What could be the solution?